# Chrome debugger - how to go to next line without entring in function?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, chrome-debugging

For example:

```
const x = 10
const f1 = () => {/* do something... */}
f1() // <<-- I'm here
console.log(x) // I want to go here without entring to f1 AT ALL but still let f1 execute.
```

I want to let `f1` execute but I don't want to go over it.

Is it possible?

---

## No duplication:

The other question is for finding a way to prevent any line from executing while this question is about letting lines that the only function calls execute but without the debugger to step into their execution.

Comment: Hard to prove a negative, but I don't think Chrome's devtools have that feature (yet). I've wanted it more than once.

Comment: @Ivar It's not. The link you provide is for finding a way to __prevent any line from executing__ while this question is about letting lines that only function calls execute but without the debugger to step into their execution.

Comment: @Ivar please remove the duplication or response.

Comment: F8 aka Step Next does exactly what you are asking for

Comment: @StavAlfi The "_without entring to f1 AT ALL_" gave me the impression that you did not want that line to be executed at all. If you just want to skip it, can't you simply add a breakpoint on the line after and hit "resume script execution"? Or hit the "Step over" button as shown in Kaspar's answer?

Comment: @Ivar your solution will make me add more than 150 breakpoints. and then deleting and adding them non-stop.

Comment: @StavAlfi I'm not sure why that would need 150 breakpoints. When you are paused on `f1()` you just either hit the "Step Over" button or add a breakpoint on the line below, hit "resume" and remove it again. If that does not do what you want then it might be useful to elaborate a bit more on your workflow.

Comment: @StavAlfi Just to be clear: You are paused on `f1()`, you want to jump the `console.log` without the debugger to enter the `f1()` function, but the code in that function should still be executed? If so, [isn't that exactly what the "Step over" button does](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwLz6.gif)?

Comment: DevTools technical writer here. @Ivar is right. **Step Over** does exactly what you want. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53949794/1669860) for a demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Ivar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53896652/chrome-debugger-how-to-go-to-next-line-without-entring-in-function#comment94639868_53896652) mentioned in the comments, the **Step Over** button does exactly what you want.

In the GIF below you can see that I'm paused on `doStuff()`. I haven't executed it yet. After clicking **Step Over** I'm paused on the line of code below `doStuff()`. The three `console.log()` statements defined within `doStuff()` have been logged to the Console. Therefore, the `doStuff()` function has executed without you needing to step through every single line of the function.

[image: demo]

See [Step through code](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/reference#stepping) to learn more about each of the code stepping buttons.

Answer (score 6):

> I want to let f1 execute but I don't want to go over it.

I assume you don't want to prevent Chrome from running `f1()` but just not having to step over it line by line.

If you want to step over multiple lines "Continue to here" from the context menu on the editor's ruler seems to be the best option:

[image: Screencast how to skip code from breaking location to later line]

The same option is available in the Firefox dev tools.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a breakpoint to the `f1()` line.
2. Comment it out `/* f1() */` and press `CMD + S` to save.
3. Press play

This way the function call will be commented out.

Comment: read the commend in the example again, please. I edited it to avoid confusion.

Comment: If you are saying you don't want to go over it, you are saying you want to go inside? Because these are the only ways you can go.